# Share a popup button menu across several popups and storyboards?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a list of string entries entered into the menu of a popup button in one of my forms. This same popup is in two other windows, on different storyboards. The items in the list are also in an array in code. For reference, here's the array:

```
static let selections = ["NTSC", "ATSC", "AM", "FM", "Other"]
```

Is there some way I can share all of this?

Ideally I would use bindings, and bind to the array. However, the menu has separators in it and I don't think I can define that in the array?

Failing that, is there a way I can put the menu on one storyboard somewhere and then refer to it from the various screens?

And failing *that*, can I easily copy the menu from one place to another? My attempts result in a new menu being created on its own in the storyboard, I can't seem to get it to paste into the popup button itself.

Answer (score 0):

An NSPopupButton internally contains an NSMenu object which provides it with the selection items. You could build a class with a class method that generates the NSMenu with the NSMenuItems you want and then set your pop up buttons' `menu` property to that generated NSMenu object.

I don't think there's a good way you can build this NSMenu in your Storyboard and have it be shareable, though; I think you'd have to create the NSMenu in code and then manually wire it up in your `viewDidLoad` method. However, you can have put the NSPopUpButton objects in your storyboards and wire those up to your controllers; you just need to manually set `menu` later for them.

Comment: It seems you can copy the Menu and then paste it into the Storyboard itself, and then bind it to the "menu" item of the button. However, I can't find a way to remove the original menu, nor a way to share it across screens. Code it is!